# How can i find item number and quantity from this raw text

Tags: php

I would like to select item number and quantity from a text, I've been stuck a bit, but have tried something to search for `_______` in the text and replace/delete characters, but I'm not really moving forward so hope someone can help me with.

The raw text is:

```
1 **1197** **3** 1,00KG ROLLER SMOKE SMOKED CA1,5KG 14811692 28.04.20 49 9992 ________ 2 **331 3** 1,00KG SALAMI POTATO CA750G 14563423 30.07.20 49 9992 ________ 3 **443 5** 1 ST OX SALAMI HALAL 200G 14946417 05.05.20 49 9992 ________ 4 **533 2** 1 PK FRANKFURTER 70G/STK 350G 15507358 05.05.20 49 9992 ________ 5 **544 1** 1,00KG SAUSAGE DELI CA1KG 14794445 05.05.20 49 9992 ________
```

The text may vary, for example, the first character is a line number (which I do not need for anything) which can be 1,2,3 ..or also.. 100,101, etc. so this must be taken into account.

I only need item number and quantity (the bold ones) from the text to use for database search, so my output schould be something like:

```
1197,3
331,3
443,5
533,2
544,1
```

Comment: Are these lines actually on their own lines in your input, and have just been co-mingled in your question, or are they one single, combined line in your input as well?

Comment: What about splitting the string by the blank characters and picking what you need by its position? Would that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take advantage of the [explode() function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```php
<?php

$str = '1 1197 3 1,00KG ROLLER SMOKE SMOKED CA1,5KG 14811692 28.04.20 49 9992 ________ 2 331 3 1,00KG SALAMI POTATO CA750G 14563423 30.07.20 49 9992 ________ 3 443 5 1 ST OX SALAMI HALAL 200G 14946417 05.05.20 49 9992 ________ 4 533 2 1 PK FRANKFURTER 70G/STK 350G 15507358 05.05.20 49 9992 ________ 5 544 1 1,00KG SAUSAGE DELI CA1KG 14794445 05.05.20 49 9992 ________';

$parts = explode('________ ', $str);
foreach($parts as $part) {
    $strings = explode(' ', $part);
    $id = $strings[1];
    $qty = $strings[2];
    echo $id . ',' .$qty."\r\n";
}
?>
```

gives:

```
1197,3
331,3
443,5
533,2
544,1
```

[See here for a live demo](https://3v4l.org/EjeBM).

Comment: I would just replace `$parts = explode('________ ', $str)` with `$parts = explode('________', $str)` (remove space after the underscores) and `$strings = explode(' ', $part)` with `$strings = preg_split('/\s+/', trim($part))` (trim the part and split by any sequence of whitespaces). You can replace `\s` with a space ` ` if you feel more comfortable.

Comment: @jotaelesalinas can you put that into a [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/) to show how it works please?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, now I can move on THANK YOU!